# How are RegExp features implemented as an NFA?

Tags: regex

I understand how simple regular expression features are implemented in an [`NFA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) such as `*`, `|`, and `()`.

I want to know how more complex features like `^`, `$`, `[]`, `[-]`, etc. are implemented. They seem simple but I'm wondering how those expressions are converted into an `NFA`.

Take this regexp for example: `^k[a-z0-9]{9}$`. How would this be converted into an `NFA`?

Comment: What does the abbreviation NFA stands for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton

Comment: Also look at Well Formed Formula and ( Extended ) Backus Naur Form, although I have yet to see a clear definition of what a Well Formed Formula is !

Comment: @user2740741 I think if we preprocess the input string by adding literal special characters such as $, ^ then regex engine will be able to match those special characters literally.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's use the same expression:

> ^k[a-z0-9]{9}$

## Sets

Each transition in an `NFA` that's used to represent a regexp is typically represented as a set, rather than a single character.

So, the transition for the "k" character gets represented as a set containing the single character, while "[a-z0-9]" is represented as a set containing these characters.

A particular implementation of an regexpr `NFA` might have an alternative, traditional, simplified transition for a single character which is what it is, but that would be probably characterized as an optimization detail.

## Anchors

Note that in regular expressions that have explicit anchoring characters, a regular expression of the form

> k[a-z0-9]{9}

Would be equivalent to

> (.*)[a-z0-9]{9}(.*)

Because that's what it is. When a regular expression is anchored, though, the NFA is literally is what it is. In other words, NFAs are always anchored to the beginning and the end of the search space, and if the anchoring character are absent, (.*) gets slapped on the beginning, or the end, of the regular expression automatically, behind the scenes.

## Repetition

> *expression*{N}

This is typically done by simply internally duplicating the regular expression *N* times. Expanding it out, explicitly.

The above would be a typical implementation of a regular expression NFA.

Comment: Input string is preprocessed to add literal special characters such as ^, $ right?

Comment: The regular expression is parsed into an external representation of the NFA state machine. "Preprocessing" in this context is meaningless. If the input string does not have anchors, the ".*" transition is the first/last transition in the internal representation of the NFA. If it does have anchors, the corresponding transition is not added. At this point, the internal representation of the NFA has little resemblance to the input string.

Comment: Your non-anchored expression would rather translate to `.*k[a-z0-9]{9}` : the `k` is important in that it must be matched, there's no need to match any additional characters, of which there might be none, and lastly there might be one either 0 or multiple preceding characters.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Be appreciated, If you could give some minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look to the [Thompson's construction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction).

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard of that algorithm, and seeing a regex laid out as an NFA nicely illustrates the backtracking (although the given examples don't). Did you present Thompson's algorithm over Glushkov's because of its simplicity or was there an other reason?

Comment: Nope, the only reason is that Thompson's is the only one I've heard about :) seems that the difference is that the resulting NFA will have no ε-transitions with Glushkov's… This paper might be of interest for the OP BTW [A Simple Way to Construct NFA with Fewer States and Transitions](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/xing2004.pdf)